# How can I remove the left indent in a longtblr?

Tags: indentation, longtblr

How can I remove the left indent in a `longtblr`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead, middlehead,lasthead}{default}{}
\begin{longtblr}[presep=-4pt,postsep=0pt]{colspec = {|p{3cm}X},\textwidth,colsep=4pt}
First    & Bla bla bla\\
Second   & Bla bla\\
Third    & Bla bla bla bla\\
Fourth   & Bla\\
Fifth    & Bla bla bla bla\\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is my desired output, where the text starts exactly at the left vertical line:

[image]

Comment: Can you specify how the result should look like?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "left indent".

Comment: Done...sorry.. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `colsep`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead, middlehead,lasthead}{default}{}
\begin{longtblr}[presep=-4pt,postsep=0pt]{colspec = {|p{3cm}X},\textwidth,colsep=0pt}
First    & Bla bla bla\\
Second   & Bla bla\\
Third    & Bla bla bla bla\\
Fourth   & Bla\\
Fifth    & Bla bla bla bla\\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

Or the `leftsep` if you only want to change the left hand side:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead, middlehead,lasthead}{default}{}
\begin{longtblr}[presep=-4pt,postsep=0pt]{colspec = {|p{3cm}X},\textwidth,colsep=4pt,leftsep=0pt}
First    & Bla bla bla\\
Second   & Bla bla\\
Third    & Bla bla bla bla\\
Fourth   & Bla\\
Fifth    & Bla bla bla bla\\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, so the ```colsep=0pt``` was the trick.. :-)

Comment: @Ommo You're welcome!